# message text not appearing in Spring Boot JSON REST error response

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rest, exception

I have followed many examples by mkyong and Bealdung but cant set the message text of the default JSON error response using Spring Boot.

Here's my ControllerAdvice class

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class InventoryControllerAdviceExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {

    @ExceptionHandler(InventoryDuplicateException.class)
    public void inventoryDuplcateHandle(HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
        response.sendError(HttpStatus.CONFLICT.value());
    }
}
```

And here's my customer exception class

```
public class InventoryDuplicateException extends RuntimeException {

    public InventoryDuplicateException(Long id) {
        super("Inventory item " + id + " exists already!");
    }
}
```

Using postman I POST the following

```
{
    "id": "1",
    "name": "orange",
}
```

What I expect to see when I throw this exception is

```
{
    "timestamp": "2020-06-29T04:37:48.023+00:00",
    "status": 409,
    "error": "Conflict",
    "message": "Inventory item 1 exists already!",
    "path": "/path"
}
```

but what I get is

```
{
    "timestamp": "2020-06-29T04:37:48.023+00:00",
    "status": 409,
    "error": "Conflict",
    "message": "",
    "path": "/path"
}
```

I've also tried passing the text explicitly

```
@ControllerAdvice
...
    response.sendError(HttpStatus.CONFLICT.value(), "the message text");
...
```

Here's the ref to the article from MKyong that I followed
https://mkyong.com/spring-boot/spring-rest-error-handling-example/

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Are you sure the InventoryControllerAdviceExceptionHandler is registered correctly ? Do you pass in the exception handler method ?

Comment: @Airy Yes. I've put break point in the method in the ControllerAdvice so I know inventoryDuplcateHandle is being called.

Comment: Does the BasicErrorController (default error controller in Spring) is called after your ControllerAdvice ? Have you registered one that override this one ?

Comment: @Airy The only ControllerAdvice registered is the one you see in the code.

Comment: Does the BasicErrorController is called ? You could put a break point in BasicErrorController::getErrorAttributes and see why the message is not added